# OpenCV - Determine position of wrist

Tags: opencv

I need to determine the position of the wrist in a frame with parts of a human under arm & matching hand.
So far I have isolated the hand & arm and I'm able to draw a polygon & hull curve around it:

[image]

I achieve this result by simple binary thresholding and automatic contour fitting.

Based on this I want to extract the location of the wrist. This needs to work for all orientations of the hand/wrist.

However, being fairly new to working with OpenCV it is unclear to me what the best way is to determine/isolate the location of the wrist. I have various ideas for this:

- The arm section is a fairly straight. Maybe a simple line detection over the contour polygon might do the job to get straight lines for the under arm.
- Somehow split the contour polygon into multiple sections. Basically it's fair to assume that the location of the wrist has the smallest distance between the two arms contouring the under arm. Is there a way to find that point along the polygon and then "cut" or "split" the polygon to get two? From there I'd have one polygon representing a rectangle which should be easy to work with.
- Use an approach that iterates along the main axis of the polygon fitted using `fitLine()`, measuring the distance between two opposing points of the polygon, finding the shortest distance.

Unfortunately I lack the experience to make the correct choice here - or even come up with a better idea.

I'd appreciate any kind of ideas & pointers towards achieving this. I could find a lot of valuable research material when it comes to hand detection & tracking and basic body part matching using Haar cascades. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to apply those technologies for my use case.

Here's some raw material (images & videos) to work with: (Google Drive Link!): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hU4hGw5dYtVrcXTq8TYWCWfcLWjT-ZJU?usp=sharing

Comment: You are trying to find wrist by morphological operations. It may only possible if you use the ratio of the polygon lengths but this is just assumption because every hand will not be in the same orientation. I think you should use an advanced algorithm like [openpose](https://www.learnopencv.com/multi-person-pose-estimation-in-opencv-using-openpose/)

Comment: I'm already using a different framework/library/technology to do the actual hand tracking. I am able to extract the landmarks of the various finger joints.
The reason I want to do this is because I don't get the actual wrist location but only the finger joint locations. Accurately determining the wrist position from that information is hard. Therefore, I want to use the plain OpenCV approach to detect the under arm and then fuse the information together to get a more accurate wrist location.

Comment: Thickness of the arm is almost same until hand. The end point of arm will be wrist. You may use this algorithm logic to get the wrist

Comment: Exactly my thought when I created this question! For me it would be very helpful if you could create an answer to the question elaborating on which approaches exist and/or which might work best and to illustrate how one would roughly achieve this using OpenCV.

Comment: Okey I can try my approach on my comment but I need some reference images which are not processed. If you can share in your question, I can try with them

Comment: I've added some material to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Did you have a chance to give your idea a try?
Under any circumstance: Could you add an answer outlining your idea so I understand your approach better and can try following that road?

Comment: I tried it before but it seems not such simple. Thanks for reminding me, I ll check it today or tomorrrow and I ll let u know. I took note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach:** I used the advantage of arm side. The thickness of arm is almost same until hitting the hand.

**Assumption:** I coded by assuming the arm will enter the screen vertically. Otherwise my code may not work. I tried all of the images you shared and its working properly for all.

**My steps:**

- Make a simple segmentation methodology for getting only needed part of the image
- Start to count the non-black pixel for each column by beginning from the arm side.
- Until hitting a column which is different from the previous column countings, you are still on the arm side. When you hit, you reached the wrist.

**Note:** I decided the threshold experimentally.

Here are the results and code:

**Input Image:**

[image]

**After segmentation:**

[image]

**Output after algorithm:**

[image]

Code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Mat src, gray, blur_image, threshold_output;

    // take input image
    src = imread("/ur/image/directory/image_01.jpg", 1);

    // convert to grayscale
    cvtColor(src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // add blurring to the input image
    medianBlur(gray,gray,9);

    // Apply a segmentation to arm
    for(int i=0; i<gray.rows; i++)
        for(int j=0;j<gray.cols; j++)
            if(gray.at<uchar>(Point(j,i))<110)
                gray.at<uchar>(Point(j,i)) = 0;

    //Creat a bgr mat to show the results clearly
    Mat copy_gray = gray;
    cvtColor(copy_gray,copy_gray,CV_GRAY2BGR);

    double sum = 0;
    int loop_cnt = 0,enter = 1;
    Point first,second;

    for(int j=gray.cols-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        loop_cnt++;
        int counter = 0,ff=1,enter2 = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<gray.rows; i++)
        {
            if(gray.at<uchar>(Point(j,i))!=0 && enter)
            {
                if(ff)
                    first = Point(j,i);
                counter++;
                ff = 0;
            }
            if(!ff && gray.at<uchar>(Point(j,i))==0 && enter2)
            {
                second = Point(j,i);
                enter2 = 0;
            }
        }

        sum += (double)counter;
        double average = sum/(double)(loop_cnt);

        if(abs(average-counter)>20.0 && enter)
        {
            line(copy_gray,Point(j,0),Point(j,500),Scalar(0,255,0),5);
            enter = 0;
        }
    }

    int distance = norm(second-first)/2;
    circle(copy_gray,Point(first.x,first.y+distance),20,Scalar(0,0,255),5);

    imshow("Result",copy_gray);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - Your example helped me getting things working the way I wanted them.

Comment: Happy to hear that